# Eclipse code formatting: Line width ignored for some situations

Tags: java, eclipse, formatter

In my eclipse formatter i set the eclipse max line width to 140 unfortunately that does not count for  something like this where the given text width is longer than 140:

```java
assertThat(rte.getMessage(),
                is("lorem ypsum sfdasdasd asdasdh asfpojkasgkl asdfjkhklasg asdjklhagjklhag asdjklhasdjkf asghjkahghjkag asghjkajkhag asghjkahgjkhagjkl asgjklhagjkhajkg aghjkhadgjklhalkg asdgjklhagjklhagl asdgjklhasjklhjklag asgjkhaksjhjkag"));
```

Another problem occurs in lines like this:

```java
private void test(final String something, final boolean something2, final Path something3, final boolean something4)throws IOException,JDOMException
```

Is there a possibility to let eclipse also format this?

Comment: no, that would be not good.... (you have to do it yourself! separate the string `" + "` (then eclipse will format(within these bounds)) or use "recent jdk features"(multi-line ..but i don't have exp. how mature eclipse is with these) `"""`)

Comment: literal strings should never be separated automatically (e.g. you search for it and would not find it), but Eclipse helps breaking the long literals, just type return inside the string, `" + "` and line break will be inserted - the second case should be working if  Formatter (Java Code Style -> Formatter) with correct settings is used. (@xen `"""` would not help, it inclludes the line breaks into the literal)